# Room + cannot find implementation DB + DB_Impl does not exist

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am getting following error while running application

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.abc.db.abdDB. abcDB_Impl does not exist
```

My build.gradle has following configuration:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

My Database class:

```
fun getDatabase(context: Context): abcDB? {
        if (dbInstance == null) {
            synchronized(abcDB::class.java) {
                if (dbInstance == null) {
                    dbInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                            abcDB::class.java, "abc_db")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build()
                }
            }
        }
        return dbInstance
    }
```

Does anyone try to use androidX API? Can someone help to find solution for this?

Comment: See a [possible answer here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274677/room-cannot-find-implementation/53669919#53669919):

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you use Kotlin, then you have to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProcessor`, and must also apply `kotlin-kapt` plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
```

Comment: thanks - adding `kotlin-kapt` worked for me (I had already put `kapt` on the dependencies), but isn't it weird that the build process wouldn't flag up that there isn't a plugin to handle the `kapt` statements

Answer (score 1):

For Java

in app build.gradle

use

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

Comment: This information is very old and outdated.

Comment: @Bink since you didn't bother on suggesting an improvement, I can do it for you. What you should do is use the following instead of the above: 

`implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"`
`annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`

$room_version is dependent on latest version released by Google

Answer (score 0):

My error was

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
    com.template.database.MoneyDatabase. MoneyDatabase_Impl does not exist.
```

I solved this by adding

```
@Database(entities = {Coins.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
```

above the database class.

Comment: This didn't work for me - the issue I believe was `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"`  should be `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-alpha1"
`

Answer (score 0):

this only worked for me

```
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha03"
```

and all dependencies will be

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'


// Room Database
def room_version = "2.4.3"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-alpha03"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin, as of Sep 2023, ksp has replaced kapt and is supported by Room.

https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

Top-level build file - build.gradle.kts (MyProject)

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false
}
```

Project-level build file - build.gradle.kts (:app)

```
plugins {
    ...
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    val roomVersion = "2.5.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.6.2")
}
```