# Room databaseBuilder build crashes

Tags: android, android-room

The following line of code crashes hard

```
Room.databaseBuilder(
        applicationContext,
        MyDatabase::class.java, "MyDB")
        .build()
```

Here's the Minimal Complete Verifiable (MCV) app you can easily duplicate

In the build.gradle for the project, make sure the following are present

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

In the build.gradle for the app, make sure the following are present

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt  "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version" // because I'm using Kotlin
}
```

All of the setup instructions is per the official document https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components

Now just use Android Studio and create a project using an "Empty Activity" template. Only 3 new files are needed in this MCV example.

Create a first file called `MyThing.kt`

```
//MyThing.kt
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity

@Entity(tableName = "myThing")
data class MyThing(@ColumnInfo var myString: String)
```

Create a second file called `MyDao.kt`

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert
import android.arch.persistence.room.OnConflictStrategy

@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(myThing: MyThing)
}
```

Create a third file called `MyDatabase.kt`

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = arrayOf(MyThing::class), version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myDao(): MyDao
}
```

Now modify the `MainActivity` class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var myDB: MyDatabase? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myDB = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            MyDatabase::class.java, "MyDB")
            .build()
    }
}
```

Running the app now will cause a hard crash on the line that I mentioned above. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: Logcat output**

`--------- beginning of crash
12-29 13:23:46.098 12801-12801/com.le.kevin.roommcv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.le.kevin.roommcv, PID: 12801
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.le.kevin.roommcv/com.le.kevin.roommcv.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.le.kevin.roommcv.MyDatabase. MyDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.le.kevin.roommcv.MyDatabase. MyDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at android.arch.persistence.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:93)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:630)
        at com.le.kevin.roommcv.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-29 13:23:46.099 777-1936/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.le.kevin.roommcv/.MainActivity`

Impl?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this. My guess is that the problem is that you are doing this on the main application thread. If so, the exception would reflect that.

Comment: So yes, the creation of the database was done in the main thread. No query has been called yet. I thought only the query would need to be executed in a separate thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Room + cannot find implementation DB + DB\_Impl does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453822/room-cannot-find-implementation-db-db-impl-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by adding

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in the build.graddle for app

I found the answer thanks to looking at the logcat suggested by the comment above, and then by the answer [Room + cannot find implementation DB + DB_Impl does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453822/room-cannot-find-implementation-db-db-impl-does-not-exist)

The official documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components is incomplete

Comment: The official documentation is not incomplete. It's your responsibility to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` when you use `kapt`. They don't have to mention it explicitly. Because with that logic, they should also add "Install Android Studio" in the beginning.